# Can you setup npm package on git for installation without exposing code?

Tags: git, npm, gitlab, npm-install, npm-package

I have some private packages in my **git repository**. I recently learned that you can install **npm packages** directly from git. I want to setup my git repo so that packages can be installed from git directly by the user of my project. This will be done by setting up users so they can access the repo as read-only users and can only use their credentials for installing.

1. What access can I give to users so that they can only install and not pull the actual code?
2. Also is there a work around anyone can suggest like may be setting up different repo for installation?

*I am using gitlab (if that matters).*

**PS:** I know about npmrc and npm private packages I am just looking into above solution for saving money and also reasearch puposes.

Comment: If they can install, they can see the actual code in their *node_modules* folder anyways, so what's the point?

Comment: @GreyFairer, I did not know that. But can you build packages/libraries so you code is hidden? I mean there should be a way to make you code secure, how do you keep your code **proprietary**??

Comment: You could minimize it, and maybe also obfuscate it, though in Javascript, you would only do that for a whole site, not for a library. If you want proprietary code, you need a compiled language like java, C, C++...